# Hue service error: Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:21050

Tags: cloudera, impala, cloudera-cdh, hue, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I have installed cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.13.0-0-virtualbox in virtual box.

Configuration Details:

CPU: 3 &  Memory: 9000MB

Now when I launch cloudera express from terminal using command

```
sudo /home/cloudera/cloudera-manager --force --express
```

Then after login in clodera manager (http://quickstart.cloudera:7180).

Start the hue service, after starting hue service, when I open this url http://quickstart.cloudera:8889/hue/editor/?type=impala

it shows me errors

> Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:21050 (code THRIFTTRANSPORT):
>   TTransportException('Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:21050',)
>
> Could not connect to quickstart.cloudera:21050

Answer (score 1):

Hue uses a few other services on the Cloudera stack, namely Hdfs, Hive, HS2, Hive Metastore, oozie, and Impala (from the quickstart). Although Hue will run without these services started you will get the error you are getting because it is trying to access Impala (Impala runs on port 21050 is how I can tell). Try starting the services mentioned through Cloudera Manager and then navigating back to Hue.